# Pull information from a calender list and displays it on the calender itself

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have a request to create some sort of buttons and when the user clicks on them the calender webpart displays those events created on it.

This has to be done in SharePoint 2013.

Example:

```
button 1   button 2   button 3
```

On click on `button 1` only events tagged with a certain category should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add e.G. 3 different icons and use them as buttons.

Then set a link to a specific URL.

In your case I would suggest to create different calendar views filtered on the event category. 
This URL would be the link in the icon.